# How to sort vuetify datatable only on header click?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In a `v-data-table`, I have one column with a simple text field, this column containing the text field is sortable. The problem is that when I change the value in the text field, the data is immediately re-sorted and in my case the lines change and in the worst case the line change and the focused input changes too, like in this example: [codepen reproduction](https://codepen.io/captain-hak/pen/BaQgKYX)

**For reproduction:**

- click on the iron header to sort the `iron` column
- change one input
- see that the line changed its position and that you're not anymore in the same field

**Expected behavior:**

- sort the `iron` column
- change one input
- see that the line didn't change its position and you can keep modify the input
- click sort again to reorder the data once you're done.

Is there a way of behaving like in the expected behavior?

Thank you very much for the answers

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should use a different event on the `<v-text-field>` component to listen for changes instead of using `v-model` to bind changes automatically to `props.items.iron`. [Text Field Event Docs here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#events)

You could do something like using the `blur` event so it only updates when your user focuses away from the text field:

```
<v-text-field
  @blur="updateIron"
  :rules="[max25chars]"
  label="Edit"
  single-line
  counter
  autofocus
></v-text-field>
```

then in your JS file you'd add a method like this:

```js
  methods: {
    // ...other stuff here
    updateIron(val) {
      this.item.iron = val
    }
  }
```

Try experimenting with different events to update your values at the appropriate time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Yes I tried those events, but that doesn't apply to my case because I really need to don't update the sort because the user will inisert a value then press tab to go to the next fields so if in the mean time to sort is changed, the ux is bad. Anyway, I found a way I will post it as an answer, Thank you again for the answer

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to that, which consist of redefining the header:
I use the slot `header.iron` in order to redefine a `sortIron` method only on `click` :  [basic demo](https://codepen.io/captain-hak/pen/abBgjXx)

What I'll have to do next is to redefine arrows, style, 'asc' and 'desc'

I'm still open to other ways of doing it!

But right now I can follow my wanted behavior which is :

- sort the table via the iron column
- change one field
- press tab, on the next field enter a value
- repeat previous step until you're done
- finally re-sort the table only by clicking the header